# How can I represent objects as an interface

Tags: javascript, json, object, interface-builder

How can I represent the following javascript object as an interface:
I did try using http://json2ts.com/, however did not give a clean and dynamic interface.
Hence, I do not want the id/codes (i.e. 6000, 6001, 6002) to be present in the interface.

```
{
    "6000": {
        "id": 6000,
        "type": "text",
        "subType": "tileDynamicSection",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://prod.assets.domain.com/uploads/myimage.jpg"
    },
    "6001": {
        "id": 6001,
        "type": "text",
        "subType": "tileDynamicSection",
        "title": "Title 2",
        "description": "Description 2",
        "imageUrl": "https://prod.assets.domain.com/uploads/myimage.jpg"
    },
    "6002": {
        "id": 6002,
        "type": "text",
        "subType": "tileDynamicSection",
        "title": "Title 3",
        "description": "Description 3",
        "imageUrl": "https://prod.assets.domain.com/uploads/myimage.jpg"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface Images {
  [key: string]: {
      id: number;
      type: string;
      subType: string;
      title: string;
      description: string;
      imageUrl: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that valid vanilla JS or is that TypeScript?

Comment: This is TypeScript